# Echo date in a prettier way

Tags: php

I'm not too good with dates in php (or any other language) and would need some help to convert a date's format into something more readable.

The string currently looks like this:

```
2021-03-31T00:00:00.0000000+02:00
```

But i would much rather prefer it to be similar to this when echo it:

```
2021-03-31 00:00:00
```

I have done some more or less useless stuff with string manipulation, but there must be a better way?

Example:

```
substr('2021-03-31T00:00:00.0000000+02:00',0,10);
```

How would one do this?

Comment: PHP has [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has pretty extensive [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) functionality that you can take advantage of, for this example you can use the `DateTime` class or `DateTimeImmutable` class.

```php
$date = new DateTime('2021-03-31T00:00:00.0000000+02:00');

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2021-03-31 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with string manipulation by

1. spliting string (e.g `$datetime`)with letter `T` to array by function [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
2. take first element and store it in a variable `$date`
3. take the second element of array and store it in `$time` (only 8 letters which represent time)

```php
$datetime = '2021-03-31T00:00:00.0000000+02:00';
$date_time = explode('T', $datetime);
$date = $date_time[0];
$time = substr($date_time[1],0,8);
echo $date.' '.$time;//2021-03-31 00:00:00
```